# Finding planar representation of graph

Tags: graph-theory

If it is known that a graph is planar, how do we find a planar representation of the graph?

Is there any method other than trial and error?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The title of this [thesis](http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/dissertations/01855269/full.pdf) looks promising: "Algorithms for Drawing Planar Graphs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing